# How to make an edittext focusable in mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I would like to know if there is a binding mechanism from a viewmodel property that provides focus (the cursor to blink or something to indicate that the textedit has focus) in a specific edittext of my choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general Mvvm question - like [MVVM Focus To Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834991/mvvm-focus-to-textbox)

Just as in the general question, in MvvmCross you could do this in some code behind in your View. For example, you could create a helper class like:

```
    public class Helper
    {
        private Activity _a;

        public Helper(Activity a)
        {
            _a = a;
        }

        // TODO - this should probably be a ViewModel-specific enum rather than a string
        private string _focussedName;
        public string FocussedName
        {
            get { return _focussedName; }
            set 
            { 
                _focussedName = value;
                var mapped = MapFocussedNameToControlName(_focussedName);
                var res = _a.Resources.GetIdentifier(mapped, "id", _a.PackageName);
                var view = _a.FindViewById(res); 
                view.RequestFocus();
            }
        }

        private string MapFocussedNameToControlName(string value)
        {
            // TODO - your mapping here...
            return value;
        }
    }
```

This could then be bound in the `View` and in `OnCreate` as:

```
    private Helper _helper;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.main);

        _helper = new Helper(this);
        this.CreateBinding(_helper)
                    .For(h => h.FocussedName)
                    .To<MyViewModel>(x => x.FocusName)
                    .OneWay()
                    .Apply();
    }
```

This code not tested - but should roughly work.