# WPF, mvvm validation and ui interaction

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I'm writing a WPF application using MVVM. I'm trying to understand how to use correctly this pattern for what concern validation.
For example, my application will manage data about articles. When a user will insert a new row, a first-step validation will mark controls needed, such as article code, quantity, description, vat...

But there is a second step validation executed by the model: for example I should check that code article will be available from vendors. I need to call one (or more) webservice and this operation can be done only by the model.
Well, when I get an incorrect result (ie, article not available) I need to return it to the viewmodel and to the view. I'd like not to show only a message, in this case I'd like to adorn code article textbox... or I'd like at least to set focus on textbox!

But... how can I do without "break" mvvm pattern? The model can return the string result, but model don't know anything about viewmodel and viewmodel don't know anything avout view... so... when I get the result from the webservice, I can return string result, I could show a messagebox with string result, but how can I refer to the code article textbox in the view in order to set focus or adorn textbox with a redline?

Obviously, this is only an example, the question is if is possibile to create a "link" (through binding?) between data passed to vm-m and controls in the ui...

Comment: It's VM job to communicate between view and model. In your case VM can have an event, rised when everything is done (`INotifyPropertyChanged` is good enough). View subscribe to it and perform additional steps (setting focus on certain control if certain property changed).

Comment: Good suggestion... but... how can I do? The user has to fill several fields. Once all values are inserted, the user click on cmdUpdate (binded to UpdateCommand). How can I inform View (adorning xaml and set focus on control) about errors?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not show any code, so I don't know whether you can apply this to your solution. But here is one approach how you could solve it. Let's assume the user has to input an article id:

```
<Label Content="Article ID"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ArticleID}"/>
<Label Content="{Binding ArticleIdVerification}" Foreground="{Binding ArticleIdForeground}"/>
```

Your view model could look like this (I neglect that you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for brevity):

```
// Viewmodel
public int ArticleID { get; set; }

public string ArticleIdVerification { get; set; }

public SolidColorBrush ArticleIdForeground { get; set; }
```

I imagine the user presses a button like "Verify". Then the view model calls a method in your model that verifies the complete input. This model method could look like this. It returns an object containing all information about whether the input was ok:

```
// Model
public async Task<VerificationResult> Verify(string articleId)
{
    var result = new VerificationResult();
    if(await ArticleIsAvailable(articleId)
    {
       result.ArticleAvailable = true;
    }

    // also verify other stuff, and add this to your result DTO
    return result;
}
```

Now after your view model called this method, it has to set all the properties:

```
// Viewmodel
private async void Verify() // this method is called by your ICommand implementation when the button is clicked
{
    var result = await model.Verify(ArticleID);
    if(result.ArticleAvailable)
    {
       ArticleIdVerification  = "OK";
       ArticleIdForeground = Brushes.Green;
    }
    else
    {
       ArticleIdVerification  = "Article not available";
       ArticleIdForeground = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

If you also want to focus the text box with wrong input, you can check this question: [MVVM Focus To Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834991/mvvm-focus-to-textbox)