# How to execute a command and change focus after a keypress in a WPF app

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF app that uses MVVM Light and I wish to both execute a command on the view model and change the keyboard focus to a specific control when the user presses ALT+SHIFT+C.

Is it possible to achieve this in an elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the shortcut key is created (if it's like Visual Studio or more like Windows - it means if you have to hold only ALT or all the keys).

But whatever the logic, You will have to first bind an Event to a Command (it might be the event keydown of one of your controls).
In MVVM Light, you will have to use Interaction.Triggers with EventToCommand (there's a lot ot explanations on google and SO)

The logic would be put here in you command.
Then a dependecy property as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596757/mvvm-how-can-i-select-text-in-a-textbox/2597085#2597085) could be implemented for getting the focus.